# MySQL GROUP BY and HAVING

Tags: mysql, group-by, having

I'm grouping my results based on a column X and I want to return the rows that has highest Column Y's value in the group.

```
SELECT * 
FROM   mytable 
GROUP  BY col1 
HAVING col2 >= (SELECT MAX(col2) 
                FROM   mytable AS mytable2 
                WHERE  mytable2.col1 = mytable.col1 GROUP BY mytable2.col1)
```

I want to optimize the query above. Is it doable without sub-queries?

I found the solution and it's simpler than you think:

```
SELECT * FROM (SELECT * FROM mytable ORDER BY col2 DESC) temp GROUP BY col1
```

Runs in 5 milliseconds on 20,000 rows.

Comment: Are you under the impression that a subquery is suboptimal?  How do you think the db engine would carry out the request, if there were another way to express it?

Comment: @harpo: True, but this example is a correlated subquery.

Answer (score 13):

Using a derived table/inline view for a JOIN:

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM mytable x
  JOIN (SELECT t.col1,
               MAX(t.col2) AS max_col2
          FROM MYTABLE t
      GROUP BY t.col1) y ON y.col1 = x.col1
                        AND y.max_col2 >= x.col2
```

Be aware that this will duplicate `x` records if there's more than one related `y` record.  To remove duplicates, use `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT DISTINCT x.* 
  FROM mytable x
  JOIN (SELECT t.col1,
               MAX(t.col2) AS max_col2
          FROM MYTABLE t
      GROUP BY t.col1) y ON y.col1 = x.col1
                        AND y.max_col2 >= x.col2
```

The following is untested, but will not return duplicates (assuming valid):

```
SELECT x.* 
  FROM mytable x
 WHERE EXISTS (SELECT NULL
                 FROM MYTABLE y
                WHERE y.col1 = x.col1
             GROUP BY y.col1
               HAVING MAX(y.col2) >= x.col2)
```

Comment: I feel like there's a LIMIT 1 solution in there somewhere

Comment: Isn't the first query wrong? I would think that the inline view would have only one row (thus not completely joining to `x`). And even then, if you grouped by col1 instead, it would only have the max for each row-specific col1

Comment: The first is returning duplicates (not useful), second is taking too long to run (3 seconds on 20,000 rows).

Comment: @Matt: No, the inline view will return rows for each col1 value.  The MAX is identical to the original query supplied.

Comment: @Elie: Did you downvote me? I don't have your tables or data to test speed.  It's up to you to index the tables.

Comment: @OMG Ponies - yep I misunderstood the question. I thought @Elie was trying to pull all rows who had a col2 equal to the  MAX(col2) for the whole _table_.

Comment: @OMG Ponies: I didn't down vote you but didn't up vote you neither... The query I provided still runs faster than yours (around half a second). I'm still looking for a better optimization (thanks for your input btw)

Comment: @Elie: Your update relies on MySQL -- it won't port to most databases (SQLite is the only one I can think of that will allow it).

Answer (score 1):

Your Col2 never be > then MAX(col2) so i suggest to use col2 = MAX(col2)

so HERE is the QUERY

```
SELECT * FROM  mytable GROUP BY col1 HAVING  col2 = MAX(  col2 )
```